# How can I change this with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to change the text value in the search box to say, for example, "Awesome Search." I know it can be done with Jquery but I can`t get it to work. Can you assist?

Note, this is the default provided by Wordpress, and it would be difficult (for me) to go in and edit the files to separate the content from the behavior, so I need Jquery to override the default. The two answers provided thus far don`t seem to do that.

```
<input type="text"
       onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'To search, type and hit enter';}"
       onfocus="if (this.value == 'To search, type and hit enter') {this.value = '';}"
       id="s"
       name="s"
       value="To search, type and hit enter"
       class="text_input">
```

Comment: *When* do you want it to show "Awesome Search"?

Comment: @Box9 oops. sorry. I want the text visible in the searchbox without the visitor having to move the cursor into the search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems you simply want to replace the default value of the textbox when the page loads, without modifying the HTML, and hence using jQuery...

```
$(function () {
    $('#s').val('Awesome Search');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, since you are using jQuery:  Get your code out of your markup.  Put this in the head of your document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var s = $('#s');
        s.blur(function() {
            if (s.val() === '') {
                s.val('To search, type and hit enter');
            }
        }).focus(function() {
            if (s.val() === 'To search, type and hit enter') {
                s.val('');
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Then in the body

```
<input type="text"
       id="s"
       name="s"
       value="To search, type and hit enter"
       class="text_input" />
```

Then you need to bind to your form submit.  Are you doing an ajax call?  It will look something along the lines of:

```
$('#theFormId').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do your ajax stuff.
    // in the callback:
    $('#s').val('Awesome Search.');
});
```

Comment: the problem is that the code I pasted in the OP is the default set up with Wordpress, so it`d be difficult (for me) to go reorganize everything. Is there a way to just replace the default text provided by wordpress?

Comment: i.e I`m trying to say I have to override the default, but I don`t think your code does that.

Answer (score 0):

The input:

```
<input type="text" id="s" name="s" value="To search, type and hit enter" class="text_input">
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('#s').focus(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == 'To search, type and hit enter'){
        $(this).text('');
    }
}

$('#s').blur(function() {
    if (strlen($.trim($(this).text())) == 0){
        $(this).text('To search, type and hit enter');
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the code I pasted in the OP is the default set up with Wordpress, so it`d be difficult (for me) to go reorganize everything. Is there a way to use Jquery to just replace the default text provided by wordpress with "Awesome search"?